# What are some problems/drawbacks with nested CSS?

Tags: css, nested, sass

I usually prefer Sass over CSS and one big reason is it allows me to write nested rules, which often reduces the amount of code I write.

I wonder, however, if there is any drawbacks of the idea. What could become problematic when writing nested CSS code?

Answer (score 2):

You should only be as specific as you need to be with CSS - it's very easy to get carried away and end up with selectors like `div#body #content #sidebar ul.results li a`, which is a) horrible to read, b) slower for the browser to interpret, and c) nearly impossible to override if you need to.

Answer (score -2):

I think debugging will be little difficult while using SASS or LESS

Comment: Actually, it's a breeze if you use something like [FireSass](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/firesass-for-firebug/).